# Positive linear map and invariant algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that we have positive linear map defined on matrix algebra:
$$
 \Phi \, \colon \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})
$$
(positive means that it maps positive-semidefinite matrices to positive- semidefinite matrices). 
Let $A\geq 0$ be such, that $\mathrm{range} \Phi(A) \subseteq \mathrm{range} A$ and $P$ be the projector onto $\mathrm{range} A$. How can I deduce, that $\Phi$ leaves the algebra $P\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})P$ invariant, i.e. 
$$
\Phi(P\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})P) \subseteq P\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})P
$$
This statement appears in the proof of characterization of irreducible positive maps. It seems that this is something obvious, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $P$ is an orthogonal projection. By an orthogonal change of basis, we may assume that $P = I_k \oplus 0_{(n-k)\times(n-k)}$ where $k$ is the rank of $A$. Thus $\mathcal M = P\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)P$ is the set of all matrices whose entries outside the leading principal $k\times k$ submatrices are zero.

Note that $\mathcal M$ is the *complex* linear span of all positive semidefinite matrices inside $\mathcal M$ (this is why the statement you want to prove is *not* true if the field is $\mathbb R$). If $\Phi(\mathcal M)$ does not entirely lie inside $\mathcal M$, we must have $Y=\Phi(X)\notin\mathcal M$ for some positive semidefinite $X\in\mathcal M$. Since $Y$ is positive semidefinite, it follows that at least one of the $n-k$ trailing diagonal entries of $Y$ is positive. But then for every small $\epsilon>0$, $Z=\Phi(A-\epsilon X)$ is a positive semidefinite matrix with a negative diagonal entry, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is the argument with diagonal entries which I was missing.

Comment: I came back to this problem, and have one more question to your answer: why matrix Y must have at least one of the n-k trailing elements positive? For example we can consider 3x3 matrix with rows (3,2,0), (5,6,0),(1,0,0) which is still positive semidefinite and it is not of the form PQP.

Comment: @HBoson What is your definition of positive semidefinite matrix? In the usual definition, a positive semidefinite matrix is a **Hermitian** matrix $B$ such that $x^\ast Bx\ge0$ for every vector $x$. The 3x3 matrix $B$ in your example is not positive semidefinite because it's not Hermitian in the first place. Moreover, $(-1,0,4)B(-1,0,4)^T=-1<0$.

Comment: Yes, I see now that my example is not good - of course positive semidefinite matrix must be hermitean (as far as i now it is the conseqence of the positivity of $x^{\star} B x$ for every x). Everything is ok, now it is clear for me why trailing diagonal elements can't be all 0.